# What happens when I team swap while I have Pokemon inside a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am toying around with the idea of swapping teams however the gym nearby was just taken over by me.  I am the sole trainer at that gym currently.

What were to happen if I swapped my team in the following situations?

- I am the sole trainer in that gym (recently taken over)
- I am holding the gym with others of the same team?

Is switching teams when you have a Pokemon in a gym even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have Pokemon in any gyms when you change teams, they will stay in the gyms. You will not be able to fight your own pokemon to bring them home, and you will not get any Pokecoins when they are returned to you. The gym will stay the original color, even if you are the only one in the gym.

My advice: Stop putting pokemon into gyms and wait for them all to come home, or else you run the risk of losing Pokecoins they could earn for you.

Source: http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-news/switch-teams-in-pokemon-go/

Comment: Perfect reply and with a source too.  Thank you!  I will let the gym takeover happen before I swap teams.